# Bash Script to append/insert Timestamp into CSV

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting, file-writing

I have a CSV file sample named RecordCountTest.csv that looks like this:

```
Date         Time           Shift         Record
26-06-2016   15:23:01       Shift2        000002
23-06-2016   09:06:24       Shift1        000001
```

When a GPIO pin wired button is pressed a bash script command is run. I would like a simple AWK or Bash script that I can call after the command is run that can document that it happened and track when. I would like to do this by inserting a row at the top (but under the header) with the current date (DD-MM-YYYY), the current time (HH:MM:SS), the shift is a variable determined by the bash script (and I will post that question in 90 minutes if I can't figure it out before then), and then increment the record by one and saving the file as RecordCountTest.CSV.  I would prefer SED if possible as that is what I am trying to learn currently and any suggestions that might help me understand the syntax more, but will accept anything that can work in this bash script including AWK.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ gawk -v OFS="\t" -v s="${shift}" 'NR==2{print strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), 
                                               strftime("%H:%M:%S"), 
                                               s, 
                                               sprintf("%06d",$4+1)} 
                                        {$1=$1}1' file > temp && mv temp file
```

if your `awk` doesn't support strftime function, you can revert to `bash`

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" -v s="${shift}" 
                  -v d="$(date +"%d-%m-%Y"$'\t'"%H:%M:%S")" 
          'NR==2{print d, s, sprintf("%06d",$4+1)} 
                {$1=$1}1' file > temp && mv temp file
```

Comment: I have only posted two questions to this site and you have answered them both with AWK solutions Karakfa! I will test and I think I should probably spend more time learning AWK than SED with the way this is leading. Thank you for the quick response. :) Stay tuned!

In the final line, the two instances of 'file' should both be replaced with the RecordCountTest.csv, correct?

Comment: anything involving math and more than text substitution `awk` is superior.     "file" is the input file, the result is written to a temp file which then overwrites the original input.  If concurrent updates are possible you may need a solution with locking or similar.

Comment: I put it into a bash script and it did not write anything the file. The file only has the pre-existing data. The script looked like this:
    
#!/bin/bash
sudo awk -v OFS="\t" -v s="${shift}" 'NR==2{print strftime("%d-%m-%Y"),
                                               strftime("%H:%M:%S"),
                                               s,
                                               sprintf("%06d",$4+1)}
                                        {$1=$1}1' /home/pi/RecordCountTest.csv $

Comment: I then ran it from the command line and this error was kicked back:
line 6: function strftime never defined

Comment: I guess strftime is `gawk` specific.  What awk version are you using?

Comment: Concurrent updates will not happen with this system. :)

Comment: I am running mawk 1.3.3

Comment: Now I get an error I had never seen before: -bash: -v: command not found
Karakfa, please don't feel obligated, I do appreciate your efforts in teaching me but I understand we do not all have time to help with every little problem.

Comment: remove the line break before the second `-v` , I formatted this way to increase readability (or put \ at the end as the line continuation)

Comment: Well it feels like progress. At least the error is new :P... 
-bash: temp: command not found

Comment: Remove the output redirection and let it go to stdout.

Comment: If that means removing the last line, then I get no error code, but it also locks up the command prompt and I have to CTRL+C to get it back...<br/>
`awk -v OFS="\t" -v s="${shift}" -v d="$(date +"%d-%m-%Y"$'\t'"%H:%M:%S")"v' NR==2{print d, s, sprintf("%06d",$4+1)}`

Comment: Still nothing changing in the file. It's ok I will just go to Python and try it from there. Thanks for all your time. :)